# Excel: Check if a set of rows is equal to another set

Tags: excel, excel-formula, countif

Is there a command in Excel to check if a set of rows is directly equal to another set. For instance I want to check if the values inside rows 1 to 10 is equal to another set of rows 13 to 22.

That is the values inside row 1 corresponds to row 13, row 2 corresponds to row 14, row 3 corresponds to row 15 and so on.

I know how to compare a row with another row using COUNTIFS(1:1, 13:13) but how to compare a range of rows using a single function?
[image: Link to Imagee]

Answer (score 3, accepted):

This will return `True` if all values are identical, `False` otherwise.

```
=AND(A1:Z10=A13:Z22)
```

This is an array formula so you must enter it using <kbd>Ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>Shift</kbd>+<kbd>Enter</kbd> rather than just <kbd>Enter</kbd>. You'll know you've done it right when Excel puts curly braces `{}` around the formula in the formula bar.

In later versions of Excel (e.g. 365) you won't need to enter this as an array formula

Comment: Beautiful solution

Comment: Thank you, what if the cell values has text too, instead of just numbers?

Comment: @jackuars, that would work as well. The formula just checks that values are the same, it isn't concerned with the type of data